# JSON request to controller giving error invalid form key

Tags: magento2, module, json

I have a custom module with a button in the admin that i want to call a controller class on click. My phtml file contains this JavaScript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],function($) {
        $('#savePricing').click(function() {
            var customurl = "XX/Pricing/Controller/SaveFamilyPriceChanges";
            $.ajax({
                url: customurl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {},
            complete: function(response) {             
                var status = response.responseJSON.status;       
                console.log(status);   
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is my XX/Pricing/Controller/SaveFamilyPriceChanges.php

```
<?php
namespace XX\Pricing\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

/**
 * Class SaveFamilyPriceChanges
 * @package XX\Pricing\Controller
 */
class SaveFamilyPriceChanges extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    private $resultJsonFactory;
        /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $customerSession;
   
    /**
     * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {    
        $response = $this->resultFactory
             ->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
             ->setData([
                 'status'  => "ok",
                 'message' => "form submitted correctly"
             ]);

        return $response;   
    }
}
```

When i click the button i am getting :

> {"error":true,"message":"Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

**Add  form key in your form**

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $block->getFormKey();?>">
```

**To get the controller url.**

```
$this->getUrl(" ");
```

Comment: Now i get this error [2020-09-07 08:59:57] main.DEBUG: URI '/admin/customer/index/edit/id/23/key/ee1f5626d4c89e0aaf91ffd421a7d1c736609c000b48112216c4ca2d871896c7/XX/Pricing/Controller/SaveFamilyPriceChanges?isAjax=true'' cannot be accessed with POST method (Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Edit) [] []
[2020-09-07 08:59:57] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action

Comment: And the error from "errorThrown" in javascript is "Not Found"

Comment: Add this in your form <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $block->getFormKey();?>">

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Could the issue be the url? looks like its adding it to the end of the current url in the error message "URI '/admin/customer/index/edit/id/23/key/ee1f5626d4c89e0aaf91ffd421a7d1c736609c000b48112216c4ca2d871896c7/XX/Pricing/Controller/SaveFamilyPriceChanges?isAjax=true''

Comment: Check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

```
<?php

$get_url = $this->getUrl("pricing/controller/savefamilypricechanges");

//use this type of name adminroutename/admincontrolername/actionfilename 

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery"],function($) {
        $('#savePricing').click(function() {
            var customurl = "<?= $get_url ?>";
            $.ajax({
                url: customurl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {},
            complete: function(response) {             
                var status = response.responseJSON.status;       
                console.log(status);   
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

***Update***

```
<?php
namespace XX\Pricing\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

/**
 * Class SaveFamilyPriceChanges
 * @package XX\Pricing\Controller
 */
class SaveFamilyPriceChanges extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    private $resultJsonFactory;
        /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $customerSession;

    private $formKey;
   
    /**
     * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {   
        $formkey = $this->formKey->getFormKey();
        $response = $this->resultFactory
             ->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
             ->setData([
                 'form_key' => $formkey,
                 'status'  => "ok",
                 'message' => "form submitted correctly"

             ]);

        return $response;   
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: I'm now getting Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null in /domains/xxxx/http/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:97

Comment: please share your block and phtml file code.